# How to synchronize separate free-running hardware timestamp components?

Tags: datetime, time, video-capture

I am working with an API from a chinese video compression board that is somewhat 'unfriendly'.  In each video frame buffer that comes back from the driver, there is a video timestamp.  However, the timestamp is broken into two separate free-running components:

1) A DateTime structure defined as

```
struct DateTime
{
    unsigned long second    :6;   // 0-59
    unsigned long minute    :6;   // 0-59
    unsigned long hour      :5;   // 0-23
    unsigned long day       :5;   // 1-31
    unsigned long month     :4;   // 1-12
    unsigned long year      :6;   // 2000-2063
};
```

2) A free-running, 16-bit (2byte) unsigned millisecond counter that rolls over.

There is nothing synchronized between these two timestamps.  The millisecond rollover does not correspond to the DateTime.second increment.  Performing a simple modulo 1000 division on the millisecond timer does not correspond to a DateTime.second increment either.

I need to come up with a way to combine both of these into a unified video frame timestamp that is always monotonically increasing.  I would like to keep the original timestamp as delivered by the driver, but overriding theirs and attaching my own timestamp is also an option.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that seems to work for the moment. Just posting it here for completeness. My approach is to maintain a running value of the 16bit unsigned millisecond counter (named 'm_timeStampOffset'), but update it only when DateTime.second changes:

```
// called at video frame rate
if (m_prevSecond != header.timeStamp.second)
{
    // save current value of 16bit millisec counter
    m_timeStampOffset = header.timeMs;
    m_prevSecond = header.timeStamp.second;
}
```

Then later on when forming the complete video frame timestamp during a client request, find the difference between the the current header.timeMs and the saved m_timeStampOffset and use that as the true millisecond timestamp:

```
#define USHORT_DIFF(t0, t1)     (((t1) < (t0)) ? 0xFFFF - (t0) + (t1) : (t1) - (t0));
// returns the full timestamp
void get_full_timestamp(VIDEO_TIMESTAMP& ts)
{
    ts.year   = 2000 + header.timeStamp.year;
    ts.month  = header.timeStamp.month;
    ts.day    = header.timeStamp.day;
    ts.hour   = header.timeStamp.hour;
    ts.minute = header.timeStamp.minute;
    ts.second = header.timeStamp.second;

    ts.milliseconds = USHORT_DIFF(m_timeStampOffset, header.timeMs);
    ts.milliseconds %= 1000;
}
```